# Field validation not updating validation message?

Tags: validation, prototypejs

I am using the validation.js from http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation to validate user input. This is what I am doing:

```
Validation.add('someClass', '', function(v, elm){

    return myValidateFunction(this, checked.value, $(hID).value, $(wID).value);

});
```

In *myValidateFunction* I set the validation message for differnet situations like this:

```
if(something) {
    validator.error = 'my message 1';
    return false;
}

if(something else) {
    validator.error = 'my message 2';
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Problem is: If the first if was true on the first request the first time, I always get the first validation message (my message 1) on all coming requests, even though the second if was true. I also debugged the JS code and when *myValidateFunction* returns and I check *this* in the function call, it has the message I want, its just not displaying it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you are right, I am using another one ... let me check what I am using, its not the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check that 'something' is false on the subsequent calls. If 'something' remains true, then the second if statement will never be reached because you return false from the first if statement and the function exits.

Other than that it's a little hard to debug without some more code to see.